# How do I query InfluxDB to show me current time and date?

Tags: time, influxdb, systemtime

I couldn't find much documentation on this. How do I query InfluxDB to show me current database system time and date?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

`SHOW DIAGNOSTICS` will do it, if you're an admin.

If you're not an admin, you can cheat:

```
precision rfc3339
INSERT foo,dummy_tag="time_test" testval=0i
SELECT last(*) FROM foo
```

Which is a bit awkward. This might deserve a feature request on their github page: https://github.com/influxdata/influxdb/issues

Answer (score 3):

Another possibility is to look at the HTTP-header of any response from the influx server. It contains a "Date" field. However, the HTTP-date field only has seconds precision.